# Xcode 6 warning with iOS Custom Framework: PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME may not be overridden for framework target 'MyFramework'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Created a blank framework in Xcode 6.1 for the Swift language and got this build warning.

```
warning: PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME may not be overridden for framework target 'MyFramework'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out I had added the build setting "Product Module Name" at the project level and this was overriding the product module name to my new framework. I have 4 targets: a production, a staging, and 2 test targets, and I didn't want to deal with 4 different bridging headers and generated headers for Swift code.

The answer was to explicitly enter a "Product Module Name" build setting for my new framework target using the correct framework name. The alternative would have been to not use a project level build setting and add it as a target level build setting for every target.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone stumbles across this problem the same way I did with Xcode 9.2, my problem was that I set the override on `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME`. The setting you want to change is `PRODUCT_NAME` (the former derives from the latter by default).

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 10.0. During development sometimes I have to change `Build System` in 
`File -> Workspace Settings... -> Build System -> New Build System(Default)`
 fixed this problem